# How to create a table with 1st row and 1st column as the header?

Tags: r

I want to create a data table in R with some data that I had already obtained. However, I'm not sure how to put those data into a table form because that required some skill to put he return data, `monthlyRet`, into the table according to their month respectively. The diagram attached below is the table format that I want, the data inside also need to be included.

Please note that the data for `No.of.Positive` and `No.of.Negative` are started from `Aug` instead of `Jan` due to the starting date in `getSymbols`. Hence, I wish the `No.of.Positive` and `No.of.Negative` can be arranged in the table created from `Jan` to `Dec` as shown in the diagram below.

The code below is how I obtained my data.

```
library(quantmod)

prices <- 
  getSymbols("^NDX", src = 'yahoo', from = "2009-07-01", to = "2019-08-01", 
             periodicity = "monthly", auto.assign = FALSE, warnings = FALSE)[,4]

return <- diff(log(prices))
r <- na.omit(exp(return)-1)

monthlyRet <- as.numeric(r)

meanMonthlyRet <- c()
No.of.Positive <- c()
No.of.Negative <- c()
for (j in 1:12){
  Group <- c()
  count_pos=0
  count_neg=0
  for (i in seq(j,length(monthlyRet),12)){
    Group[i] <- monthlyRet[i]
    if(monthlyRet[i]>0){
      count_pos <- count_pos+1
    }
    else  if(monthlyRet[i]<0){
      count_neg <- count_neg+1
    }
  }
  meanMonthlyRet[j] <- mean(Group, na.rm=TRUE)
  Positive=0
  Negative=0
  if(meanMonthlyRet[j]>0){
    Positive=count_pos
    Negative=10-Positive
  }
  else if (meanMonthlyRet[j]<0){
    Negative=count_neg
    Positive=10-Negative
  }
  No.of.Positive[j] <- Positive
  No.of.Negative[j] <- Negative
}

# My data required in table #--------------------------------------------------

Year <- c(2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019)
Month <- c("Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul")
r
No.of.Positive
No.of.Negative
```

I hope I can obtain exactly the same table format and content as the diagram below (I manually created in excel). Further, if the `start` and `end` date in `getSymbols` are changed, I hope the data in the table will still be correct.

[image]

Comment: Is this only for report purpose? Then you can use kableExtra, flextable, etc

Comment: Ya, is for a report purpose but I have no time to start again to learn this two packages again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse solution for your problem.

```r
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)

prices <- getSymbols("^NDX", src = 'yahoo', from = "2009-07-01", 
                     to = "2019-08-01", periodicity = "monthly", 
                     auto.assign = FALSE, warnings = FALSE)[,4]

r <- prices %>% 
  log %>% 
  diff %>%
  exp %>% 
  {. - 1}

table_out <- r %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  set_names(c("date", "variable")) %>% 
  mutate(variable = (variable * 100) %>% round(2)) %>% 
  separate(date, c("year", "month", "day")) %>% 
  select(-day) %>% 
  spread(month, variable)

n_pos <- map_dbl(table_out, ~sum(. > 0, na.rm = T))
n_neg <- map_dbl(table_out, ~sum(. < 0, na.rm = T))

table_out <- table_out %>% 
  mutate_if(is.double, ~str_c(., "%")) %>% 
  rbind(n_pos, n_neg)
x <- nrow(table_out)
table_out[(x-1):x, "year"] <- c("No. of Positive","No. of Negative")
table_out
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works for me! However, after I run the code, I realised the No.of Positive and No.of Negative for Jan is 8 and 2 respectively instead of 6 and 4.      8 and 2 is the data for Feb, seems like the data advance one month before for every month. How should I adjust that? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Further, if it is possible, I hope the data for the returns could have a "%" behind and the No. of Positive/Negative showed in the table would have no decimal point. Thanks!

Comment: I made an error in an edit of the code which led to the problem with the misaligned number. I have edited it and also included the changes from your second comment

Comment: Btw, do you have any suggestion on how to change the `NDX.Close` in the code to a more general one so that next time when I change the ticker in `getSymbols`, I no need to manually change the `NDX.Close` again. Thanks!

Comment: you could use `set_names()`

Comment: Can you edit in the solution given by you with the set_names? Because I realised I unable to do that because of the `" "` for the `NDX .Close`, it seems like only print the text for me instead of the names.

Comment: I've added it, but if you want to use the code regularly, you might want to try to understand how it works, so you can adapt it yourself, if necessary

Comment: Ya, I enconter similar problem before and I couldn't solve it. Can you brieftly explain what does it means for the line `set_names(c("date", "variable")) %>% 
  mutate(variable = (variable * 100) %>% round(2)) ` ? My another doubt will be `mutate_if(is.double, ~str_c(., "%"))`. These two code are the one that I don't really understand, hope you can clear my doubt! Thank you.